# What is the difference in meaning between "I agree" and "I am agreeing"?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, stative-verbs

I am aware of the fact that the standard way of using agree is in the Present Simple. And until recently I thought it's only correct to use it that way when talking about present situations. But in the TV show *Friends* Ross used it in the present continuous. The context is he tries to convince Phoebe's coworker not to tell Phoebe that Ross cheated on Rachel to prevent Pheobe from telling it to Rachel. Here is the excerpt:

> You did a bad thing!
>
> Ross: Yes, I did.
>
> Jasmine: Very bad!
>
> Ross: Very bad.
>
> Jasmine: Very, very bad.
>
> Ross: **I’m agreeing with you**. Did you, listen, did you happen to
>   tell Phoebe yet?

What does he try to communicate using *agree* in the present continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She says "You did a bad thing!". He says "Yes I did." At that point, he has already agreed, and he could have said "I agree."
 She repeatedly insists that he did something bad. Finally, he must insist that he continues to agree; there's no need for her to continue insisting.

Comment: So he used it in the present continuous for emphasis, right?

Comment: Yes, that would emphasize that it continued right up to the present.